# How to write a program that intercepts input before it reaches the kernel?

Tags: c++, c, windows, input, kernel

There is this program *install-interception.exe*, which can be downloaded from here: http://www.oblita.com/interception.html

It intercepts any kind of input, before it reaches the kernel. It allows me, for example, to differentiate between multiple keyboards on windows-level. Anyway, this is a very handy program, but I have no idea how it works. This is all I can find about the source code: https://github.com/oblitum/Interception/issues/5

So I'm using something I don't understand so, I want to ask if you can point me into the direction of how to write a c/c++ program of how to do the same.

**Edit:**

I thought I might as well describe what I use this program for.
Using this input-interceptor, I've written a program that allows me to do the following:
I have one main keyboard, and one macro keyboard. The main keyboard works normally, but the macro keyboard has a few extra features.
These features are are activated by pressing a button on the macro keyboard, what buttons do what are decided by an XML file that is loaded when the program starts. These are the features:

- Insert text
- Enable/disable keyboard input capture + write input to file
- Copy to clipboard 1/2/3, etc
- Paste from clipboard 1/2/3, etc
- Run program (Example, start chrome, run batch files)
- Find next instance of program X/Y/Z, and put it on the screen. For example: Find next instance of "Visual Studio" and put it on the front screen. Basically an Alt-Tab replacement.
- Put stickers on macro keyboard buttons so I can easily identify what each button does :D :D

Basically I wrote this very handy program with the interception API, but I don't know how the input is intercepted before it is passed to the API, I want to learn how, so I can more completely understand my program.

Comment: The only way to intercept input events before they reach the kernel is to override the interrupt handlers for whatever device you want to read from. The problem with this is that it's includes hacking the kernel in bad ways, and that you really have no idea what windows the input events happened for. What your program does is probably install a hook somewhere where such hooks can be inserted, and the kernel passes the events together with window and process information, and it's up to the program to pass the event on or not in the chain.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, I want to know how to do that! I wrote a program for myself that allows me to have one main keyboard, and one macro keyboard where each button does something special (macros, multiple clipboards, run programs/files) Very handy tool :-) , and I want to know how to write it for myself, instead of depend on this program I know nothing about. I do not get, nor do I want, the window/process information, I just get the input codes, and if they are for the macro keyboard, I intercept it and run macros.

Comment: So you're trying to write a keylogger?

and writing tht sort of code would be very low level, and frankly I don't think we should support malware writers attempts to write malware...

Comment: "so I can more completely understand my program" Ehm... you should **first** understand what you want to do **then** write your program. You seem to  put the cart before the horse. Oh, ynd I agree with @MarcusJ. I do not think we should support spyware.

Comment: @Olaf, main program is already written, I just want to know how *install-interception.exe* works.

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork  you did not post ANY of your main program. I am also VTC 'cos malware potential.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: there's probably no need for interrupt handlers, a filter driver should do.  Technically that isn't "before it reaches the kernel" but in this context I'm fairly sure "before it reaches the top of the keyboard driver stack" is all that's *actually* necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a part of the answer:

There's user mode, and kernel mode. I think I need a program that runs in kernel mode.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554836(v=vs.85).aspx

I think I will understand how *install-interception.exe* is programmed by reading & learning from the following 3 tutorials:

http://www.adlice.com/kernelmode-rootkits-part-1-ssdt-hooks/

http://www.adlice.com/kernelmode-rootkits-part-2-irp-hooks/

http://www.adlice.com/kernelmode-rootkits-part-3-kernel-filters/

I have a lot of reading to do :O

Comment: SetWindowsHookEx should help, and is possible in userland. You may want to hook WH_KEYBOARD or WH_KEYBOARD_LL.